# A simple prog in Python. Involves digits of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

So basically, this prog reads 5 numbers:
X, Y, startFrom, jump, until

with space separating each number. an example:

```
3 4 1 1 14
X = 3
Y = 4
1 = startFrom
jump = 1
until = 14
```

In order to do that, I used:

```
    #get X, Y, startFrom, jump, until
    parameters = raw_input()

    parametersList = parameters.split()

    X = int(parametersList[0])
    Y = int(parametersList[1])
    #start from startFrom 
    startFrom = int(parametersList[2])
    #jumps of <jump>
    jump = int(parametersList[3])
    #until (and including) <until>
    until = int(parametersList[4])
```

The program outputs a chain (or however you would like to call it) of, let's call it `BOOZ` and `BANG`, when `BOOZ` is X if exists in the number (i.e X is 2 and we are at 23, so it's a BOOZ) . in order to check that (I used: `map(int, str(currentPos))` when my `currentPos` (our number) at first is basically `startFrom`, and as we progress (add jump every time), it gets closer and closer to `until`), or if X divides the currentPos (`X%num == 0`. i.e: X is 2 and we are at 34, it's also a `BOOZ`).

`BANG` is the same, but with Y. If `currentPos` is both `BOOZ` & `BANG`, the output is `BOOZ-BANG`.

`startFrom, startFrom+ jump, startFrom+2*jump, startFrom+3*jump, ..., until`

We know the numbers read are `int` type, but we need to make sure they are valid for the game.
X and Y must be between 1 and 9 included. otherwise, we print (fter all 5 numbers have been read): `X and Y must be between 1 and 9` and exit the prog.
In addition, jump can't be 0. if it is, we print `jump can't be 0` and exit the prog. Else, if we can't reach`until` using `jump` jumps (if `startFrom+ n * jump == until` when `n` is an int number) so we need to print `can't jump from <startFrom> to <until>` and exit the prog.
My algorithm got too messy there with alot of ifs and what not, so I'd like an assistance with that as well)

so for our first example (`3 4 1 1 14`) the output should be:

```
1,2,BOOZ,BANG,5,BOOZ,7,BANG,BOOZ,10,11,BOOZ-BANG,BOOZ,BANG
```

another example:

```
-4 -3 4 0 19
```

OUTPUT:

```
X and Y must be between 1 and 9
juump can't be 0
```

another:

```
5 3 670 7 691
```

OUTPUT:

```
BOOZ,677,BANG,691
```

another:

```
0 3 4 -5 24
```

OUTPUT:

```
X and Y must be between 1 and 9
can't jump from 4 to 24
```

another:

```
3 4 34 3 64
```

OUTPUT:

```
BOOZ-BANG,BOOZ,BANG,BOOZ-BANG,BANG,BANG,BANG,55,58,61,BANG
```

my prog is toooo messy ( I did a while loop with ALOT of ifs.. including if `currentPos==until` so in that cause it won't print the comma (`,`) for the last item printed etc.. but like I said, all of it is so messy, and the ifs conditions came out so long and messy that I just removed it all and decided to ask here for a nicer solution.

Thanks guys
I hope it was clear enough

Comment: I am not clear on the question being asked. Is there a problem with the code? The only thing I see is that your code is messy and you would like help to clean it up, but you will need to post code to get that help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

I did't post my code because (not only is it not accurate and yields inaccurate results most of the times) I know this is not the way to do it and I wanted to see how you guys would write such code. I get too many ifs and what not.. for example for the first part, when we just check to see if we can jump from the start to the `until`, there are so many things to check, because the numbers can be also negative (as shown in the examples) and I can't continue doing `if this is negative and that is positive etc etc etc`... it's too messy and I can't even keep up :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version has no `if` :)

```
parameters = raw_input()
sx, sy, sstartfrom, sjump, suntil = parameters.split()
x = "0123456789".index(sx)
y = "0123456789".index(sy)
startfrom = int(sstartfrom)
jump = int(sjump)
until = int(suntil)
for i in range(startfrom, until+jump, jump):
    si = str(i)
    booz = sx in si or i%x == 0
    bang = sy in si or i%y == 0
    print [[si, 'BANG'],['BOOZ','BOOZ-BANG']][booz][bang]
```

Easiest way to get the commas is to move the loop into a generator

```
def generator():
    for i in range(startfrom, until+jump, jump):
        si = str(i)
        booz = sx in str(i) or i%x == 0
        bang = sy in str(i) or i%y == 0
        yield [[si, 'BANG'],['BOOZ','BOOZ-BANG']][booz][bang]

print ",".join(generator())
```

---

Sample output

```
$ echo 3 4 1 1 14 | python2 boozbang.py
1,2,BOOZ,BANG,5,BOOZ,7,BANG,BOOZ,10,11,BOOZ-BANG,BOOZ,BANG
$ echo 5 3 670 7 691 | python2 boozbang.py 
BOOZ,677,BANG,691
$ echo 3 4 34 3 64 | python2 boozbang.py 
BOOZ-BANG,BOOZ,BANG,BOOZ-BANG,BANG,BANG,BANG,55,58,61,BANG
```

Comment: Holy sh*t, you are quick.
First of all thanks a lot!
secondly, damn. you used so many things I am not familiar with, but before asking about them or trying to search them up and understand, I tried to run the code and test it as well, but it failed - 
for my first example it yields wrong results, and for some results it even returns an error

Comment: @user2997196, not sure why it's not working for you. can you elaborate? My error messages are different because I'm letting it throw builtin exceptions. The one with a negative step doesn't have any output, but you should be able to work out how to fix that

Comment: Yes, I must have mixed something up, it is now working, but doesn't yield the error messages when needed, and also for some examples it yield a Pythonic error message, for example, for `-4 -3 4 0 19` I get:

    `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\booz.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = "0123456789".index(sx)
ValueError: substring not found`    

I'm gonna go over this code and hopefully with your help try to understand it guys, so I will be able to also fix it accordinally and modify it (I'm new to Python D:)

Comment: what is the difference between :
`sx, sy, sstartfrom, sjump, suntil = parameters.split()`
to what I did :

`parametersList = parameters.split()

    X = int(parametersList[0])
    Y = int(parametersList[1])
    #start from startFrom 
    startFrom = int(parametersList[2])
    #jumps of <jump>
    jump = int(parametersList[3])
    #until (and including) <until>
    until = int(parametersList[4])`

other than being shorter?

Comment: @user2997196, I keep str versions of all the variables for convenience, even though I only end up using `sx` and `sy` later.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks
I get what you did with the builtin function `range()` there, but I don't understand the use of `i`.. how does it know to make that jump? is it just the way python works?
plus another thing. is your `sx in si` the same as what I used: `x in map(int, str(i))`?

And one more thing about the code, the most crucial imo, because I don't understand this line AT ALL.. could you or anyone else please explain that to me? `yield [[si, 'BANG'],['BOOZ','BOOZ-BANG']][booz][bang]`

and lastly, how would you do the check I mentioned in the main post?
http://puu.sh/5vuf8.png
continued:

Comment: your code is so elegant and, like you said, contains no ifs at all
You prolly have a method for this as well?
thanks a lot again!

Comment: ? O: anyone?
I don't like using codes I don't fully understand, and in this case it isn't even finished so I have to understand it in order to modify it further =[

Comment: Okay so I managed to complete the program (printing errors and everything when needed, etc) but I still don't understand `[[si, 'BANG'],['BOOZ','BOOZ-BANG']][booz][bang]`.. I would still very much appreciate it if someone took the time to explain it to me because I really want to learn =[ I accepted this answer, thanks.

Comment: I also managed to understand `[[si, 'BANG'],['BOOZ','BOOZ-BANG']][booz][bang]`.. it is so brilliant..
it starts from [false,true] for `booz`, and then moves onto `bang` and check the sub-category
it's so brilliant
and i'm curious to know, without using this line, how else would you  do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def CheckCondition(number, xOrY):
    return (xOrY in str(number)) or not (number % xOrY)

def SomeMethod(X, Y, start, jump, end):
    for i in range(start, end, jump):
        isPassX = CheckCondition(i, X)
        isPassY = CheckCondition(i, Y)
        if isPassX and isPassY:
            print "BOOZ-BANG"
        elif isPassX:
            print "BOOZ"
        elif isPassY:
            print "BANG"
        else:
            print i



def YourMethod():
    (X, Y, start, jump, end) = (3, 4, 1, 1, 14)
    if (X not in range(1, 10) or Y not in range(1, 10)):
        print "X and Y must be between 1 and 9"
    if jump <= 0:
        print "juump can't be less than 0"

    SomeMethod(X, Y, start, jump, end)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and your effort but sadly I can only try to understand one code at a time, so I don't want to bother you for no reason and so I'm just trying to understand gnibbler's

Thanks a lot again, I really appreciate that and I don't want your post to go by unnoticed!